# Access Denied After SSL Changes on Resource URL Admin Page

Tags: civievent, drupal, administer, resource-urls

**Setup**: CiviCRM 4.6.4, Drupal 7.54, GoDaddy Shared Hosting.

**What I Did Recently**: Installed Let's Encrypt certificates, verified things still worked, created and sent out a bulk mailing, created and tested an event with online signup and payment.

**What I Did Friday (6/23/17)**: (not completely clear of exact steps here 'cause I may have blanked while banging my head on desk... note to self, glue foam on desktop) Under Administer/System Settings/Resource URLs I changed the SSL settings to Yes and then back to No.

**What Happened Next**: Access Denied error trying to access ANY Administer page, pages that access creation/editing of Events, forward facing Event pages, other pages that are less important to me right now.

**What I Need**: HELP (please)!  Event is little more that 3 weeks away and I (we) need access.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the SSL settings in `civicrm.settings.php`, which will hopefully be enough to get you back in.

Add the following lines to `civicrm.settings.php`:

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['verifySSL'] = false;
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['enableSSL'] = false;
```

Sources:

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Override+CiviCRM+Settings
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/settings/Core.setting.php

Comment: Thank you ever so much!  Solved my issue AND same-day service.  BARGIN!